# Understanding a coding challenging in finding the first duplicate value in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently practicing with my coding skills and one of the challenges I ran into was finding the first duplicate value produced in an array. I had solve the challenge, but not in a timely manner. I looked at the solution for the problem and ran into this solution and wanted help in understanding how it exactly works. I have the solution commented in the areas that I understand and what exactly is the purpose of that block of code, but I would like help in understanding the if-statement why it works the way it does.

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        //Checks ???????????
        if(a[Math.abs(a[i])-1]<0)
            return Math.abs(a[i]);
        //Make the checked value negative
        else{
            a[Math.abs(a[i])-1]=-a[Math.abs(a[i])-1];
        }
    //If there are no duplicates it returns -1
    return -1;
}
```

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ a.length ≤ 105,
1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length.
```

Comment: The best solution is the solution that is clear and easy to understand. While there's something useful to learn here, that code is not easy to understand or even how/why it works. Strive for code that is obvious in its purpose, not code that is a cryptic puzzle.

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-

Comment: This is a truly stupid solution to the problem. It seems to be designed to indicate how smart the writer is while actually proving the opposite. But, to answer your question, essentially how it works is to use 'value in position i is negative' to mean 'value i has already been seen'.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I will not give you the exact answer but instead provide you with tools for you to figure it out.

In order for you to figure out this code, you need to debug it. Here are some ways you could go about it.

1. Set a breakpoint just prior to calling the function (look up how to do this for your IDE), thereafter step into your code line-by-line.
2. You could use a combination of temporary variables and `System.out.println()` statements. Looking into your code, break it down into modular bits that you can track. For instance you could re-write the expression inside the `if` statement as

   ```
   int currentElementAbsolute = Math.abs(a[i]);
   System.out.println(currentElementAbsolute);

   int difference = currentElementAbsolute - 1;
   System.out.println(difference);

   int element = a[difference]
   System.out.println(element);

   if (element < 0)
   {
      return Math.abs(a[i]);
   }
   ```

   As you can see, for each operation/line, I print out the current value thus keeping track of events. Practice this and re-write the `else` part

*PS: Upon completion you will realise this method fails to capture all duplicates when certain type of numbers are used. Happy Hunting :)*